# Why is Java saying my file doesn't exist? (Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: partyResponses.txt (No such file or directory))

Tags: java, file

I'm just learning how to use Java, and I have an assignment that asks us to create a file, yet Java is telling me that the file doesn't exist and I don't know why. I'm supposed to make sure my file exists before proceeding with anything else. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Party {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("party.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("The file party.txt doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you file is located in the project tree, or just provide an absolute path.

Comment: Hint: print the absolute path of the file to see where it is supposed to be `System.out.println("The file doesn't exist: " + file.getAbsolutePath());` - when printing error message, add useful (debug) information to it

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the complete file path:

```
File file = new File("C:/users/.../party.txt");
```

Or you can use relative paths. Let's say you have your `Party` class inside a `sketchbook` package. Your relative path would be:

```
File file = new File("src/sketchbook/party.txt");
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion yet I'm still receiving the same error and I'm not sure why.